# ColdFusion Builder 3 debugging

Tags: debugging, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I really like the new ColdFusion Builder, but am running into trouble configuring debugging.  I've gone through the tutorials on setting up a project and a ColdFusion Server.  Everything seems fairly straightforward.  I have a standard CF 10 install running on IIS.

Here are my CF Server settings:

**Application Server:** defaulted to CF+Tomcat Bundle; not sure how to tell if it should be something different

**Server home:** C:\ColdFusionBuilder3\ColdFusion\cfusion

**Document root:** C:\inetpub\wwwroot

RDS is enabled, and I am able to start the CF server; however, if I run the project I get a blank page, and I see the error below in the Console.  Not sure how to fix it, though.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[defaultLocal]:Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 6006
[defaultLocal]:(06/10 at 08:53:26) Server is available. Getting server settings.
[defaultLocal]:FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
[defaultLocal]:ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
[defaultLocal]:ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
[defaultLocal]:JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
```

Comment: seems like the port 6006 is the problem

Answer (score 1):

I could only get this working by setting it up as a remote server when using IIS since I have coldfusion running as a windows service. I use port 80.

Also, note that CFBuilder 3, which is extremely buggy, forgets your remote server every time you shut down Eclipse. They are supposed to be patching this. I am very disappointed that we spent any money on this garbage software. Unfortunately, there aren't any IDEs that understand ColdFusion 10+ other than text editors such as Sublime.

Comment: So did you set up IIS as a server under CF Servers?  I agree, CFBuilder 3 is less than ideal, but I like it better than Sublime so far.  If nothing else, it is easier on the eyes.